# How to identify the killer in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a zombie game with a statically created zombie. I can capture when he is killed:

```
local Humanoid = script.Parent.Zombie
function zombieDied() 
local tag = Humanoid:findFirstChild("creator") 
    if tag ~= nil then 
    end 
Humanoid.Died:connect(zombieDied)
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to identify which player killed him. That tag value is always nil.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you zombies being killed? I'd presume bullets and remotes are used?

Comment: FPS (and yes, bullets). Do I need to update the creator on the zombie from my weapon? If so, what event do I attach that to?

Answer (score 0):

Update the creator, when you take damage from the humanoid of the zombie.